# Pasar por una variable el nombre del campo @Query JPA | QUERY JPA DINAMICO

Tags: java, spring, sql, jpa, jpql

espero y me puedan ayudar.

¿Como puedo concatenar a una variable el nombre de un campo con jpql?

**Actual mente lo tengo de esta manera y funciona correctamente la consulta**
    @Repository
    public interface CiudadRepository extends JpaRepository {

```
    @Query(value="SELECT  c.city as ciduad," + " c." + "firstname as nombre FROM contact c",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Ciuda> obtenerCiudad(@Param("parametro")String parametro);

}
```

**Lo que deseo es que mi parametro ocupe el lugar del campo ciudad para asi poder pasar los campos que yo requiera de manera dinamica:**

```
@Repository
public interface CiudadRepository extends JpaRepository<CiudadEntity, String> {

    @Query(value="SELECT  c.city as ciduad," + " c." + "*:parametro* as nombre FROM contact c",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Ciuda> obtenerCiudad(@Param("parametro")String parametro);

}
```

**¿Como puedo hacer este tipo de consulta?**

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer es una proyección, pero no puedes hacerlo directamente en JPA, porque los métodos del repositorio retornan o bien una entidad del tipo que le especificaste, o bien una colección de ellos.

Lo que tienes que hacer es definir una interface para cada proyección distinta que necesites, con los datos que necesites:

```
public interface Ciudad {
    String getCiudad();
}
```

Luego tu repositorio:

```
@Repository
public interface CiudadRepository extends JpaRepository<CiudadEntity, String> {

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM contact c", nativeQuery = true)
    <T> List<T> obtenerCiudad(Class<T> type);
}
```

y luego, lo puede llamar así:

```
List<Ciudad> ciudades = obtenerCiudad(Ciudad.class);
```

Puedes agregar más parámetros a tu query si quieres filtrar por algún atributo, pero el último parámetro tiene que ser el tipo (interface) que retornará tu proyección.

Comment: Te ha servido esta respuesta? Si es así, puedes darla como correcta por favor.